# Как избежать перекомпиляции файлов теста в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, юнит-тесты

В Qt для тестирования должен создаваться отдельный исполняемый файл, а значит, и отдельный проект, для каждого теста. Напрашивается решение объединить эти проекты в subdirs. Вот главный файл program.pro:

```
template = subdirs
am.subdir = MainProgram
Testing.subdir = Testing
subdirs += am Testing
```

В файл MainProgram.pro включены все исходные файлы проекта. В файл Testing.pro включены все исходные файлы, за исключением main.cpp, а также файл, содержащий тестовый класс.

Такой подход приводит к тому, что все файлы, которые находятся в двух и более проектах, компилируются несколько раз. Можно ли этого избежать? Или, может быть, существуют более эффективные подходы к организации тестирования?

Comment: в subdirs если изменений не было, и делаете не "пересобрать" а просто "собрать", проект повторно не компилируется  (будет просто reading ....pro)

Comment: *"а значит, и отдельный проект, для каждого теста"* - ничего подобного. Делайте все тесты в одном проекте.

Comment: просто в тесты нужно добалять не cpp, файлы, а obj (.a) файлы и хедеры. И тогда ничего не будет дважды перекомпилироваться.

Comment: @user7860670, макрос [QTEST_MAIN](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#QTEST_MAIN) раскрывается в функцию `main`. Макрос принимает только один параметр - тестовый класс. Следовательно, в одном исполняемом файле может быть только один тестовый класс.

Comment: @KoVadim, добавлять объекты - интересная мысль, и это работает, если прописать в `.pro` все зависимые объектные файлы вручную. А можно как-то добавить все, кроме `main.o`?

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, проблема не в этом, а в том, что один исходный файл входит в два и более проекта. Поэтому компилируется два раза.

Comment: Для запуска тестов из нескольких тестовых классов следует использовать `QTest::qExec`. А если *" исходный файл входит в два и более проекта"* то его надо выносить в третий проект и инклюдить / линковать в первые два.

Answer (score 0):

Просто добавьте `-nomake tests` в конфигурации

Answer (score 0):

По совету KoVadim решил добавить в проект тестов объектные файлы тестируемого проекта. Для этого я создал файл tests_common.pri следующего содержания:

```
#не OUT_PWD!
#Здесь можно добавить условие по конфигурации debug/release
TESTABLE_OBJECTS_DIR = $$PWD/../MainProgram/debug

AllFiles = $$files($$TESTABLE_OBJECTS_DIR/*$$QMAKE_EXT_OBJ)
AllFiles -= $$TESTABLE_OBJECTS_DIR/main$$QMAKE_EXT_OBJ

OBJECTS += $$AllFiles
```

Переменная AllFiles содержит все объектные файлы, кроме main.o.

Этот файл я добавляю с помощью `include` в каждый тестовый проект, и в результате тестовый исполняемый файл успешно линкуется. Однако тут появляется ограничение: основной проект должен быть скомпилирован до того, как будет выполнен qmake для тестового проекта, иначе тестовый проект не увидит все необходимые объектные файлы.

Можно было бы предположить, что для этой цели можно использовать переменную `OBJECTS` из qmake, но в моём случае она [оказалась пуста](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70981161/5767249). Почему? Ответа нет.

> Для запуска тестов из нескольких тестовых классов следует использовать QTest::qExec.

В [руководстве](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qttestlib-tutorial1-example.html) такого нет. И в самих исходниках Qt используется именно подход с subdirs, где каждый тест находится в отдельном проекте. Хотя там подключение тестируемых библиотек производится с помощью `Qt += ...`, поэтому такой проблемы там нет.